# pdftoraster missing from ghostscript-cups package on fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, cups, ghostscript, avahi

Attempting to get AirPrint running on an old laser network printer (so my kid can print from his iOS device) with `avahi-daemon`, `cups` and [this python script](https://github.com/tjfontaine/airprint-generate).

I've followed the instructions as per this blog post: http://thepoch.com/post/32724116678/get-linux-airprint-working-again-for-ios-6.

I can print a test page from `cups` without issue. The problem stems from `pdftoraster` missing from the set of `cups` filters when the service is invoked via `avahi`; as required from this line:

```
echo "image/urf application/pdf 100 pdftoraster" > /usr/share/cups/mime/airprint.convs
```

I see this log error in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
E [09/Feb/2013:22:29:25 -0500] Filter "pdftoraster" not found.
```

Missing!:

```
[anew@bucket ~]$ ls /usr/lib/cups/filter/ | grep pdftoraster
[anew@bucket ~]$
```

Has anyone seen this before? It looks like the ghostscript-cups package I'm using is up-to-date;

```
[anew@bucket ~]$ yum list installed ghostscript-cups
Installed Packages
ghostscript-cups.x86_64                                                    9.06-3.fc17                                                     @updates
[anew@bucket ~]$
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work!

The correct line to add to mime.convs in the raster filter section (or airprint.convs if you did that) is

**image/urf           application/vnd.cups-raster 100 imagetoraster**

Do not use pdftoraster.  Make it just like the other imagetoraster lines.

Now we can print from our iPad!

Comment: Thanks! I modified my original setup to use this setting and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like if I symlink `/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster` to `/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster` I'm able to at least get printing working. Although it seems like I can only get the iOS device to print images, printing from Safari doesn't work at all.

Can someone please comment on this? I would like to know if your experience with `cups`/`avahi` AirPrinting is similar.